# Why does this simple Webflux Controller calls the Webclient retrieve method twice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a very simple Webflux controller that just do a GET request to another service endpoint and returns a simple JSON list. The problem is the remote endpoint is always called twice.

This issue doesn't happen if I used Mono as the return type of the controller instead of Flux!

```
// This calls "/remote/endpoint" twice!

@GetMapping("/blabla")
fun controller() : Flux<JsonNode> {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/remote/endpoint")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JsonNode::class.java)
            .flatMapIterable { body ->
                body.get("data")
            }
}

// This calls "/remote/endpoint" once.

@GetMapping("/blabla")
fun controller() : Mono<JsonNode> {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/remote/endpoint")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JsonNode::class.java)
            .map { body ->
                body.get("data")
            }
}
```

Comment: Ever found out the answer to this one?

Comment: No unfortunately, I had to switch to use Mono instead of Flux for everything...

Comment: I was facing the same issue but for me the issue was in subscribe method. Removing the method resolve the issue.

Comment: Wow, I am facing a similar issue.  I have a service that gets invoked twice from a controller.  The controller I just updated to use Mono.  I don't subscribe anywhere int 
the call chain though ... I do have a couple of .doOnSuccess handlers... Ill explore them a little bit more and maybe replace with a .map instead.